# Not using the right idexes?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

I am trying to implement a subset-sum problem. So the base idea is that we have a container with some capacity C and also we have glasses with Capacity -c- and we would like to fill the C with EXACTLY -C-litres. Now let me show you what I have done.

*I will ommit the class `container` as it is an object and does not really affect the algorithm itself:

```
public static int calcolaNumeroContenitori(int C, ArrayList<Contenitore> p)
    {

        boolean B[][] = new boolean[p.size()][C];
        boolean U[][] = new boolean[p.size()][C];

        B[0][0] = true; 
        U[0][0] = false;
        int num_cont = 0;
        int j;
        int i;
        //prima riga - caso base
        for( j = 0; j < C; j++)
        {
            if(j == p.get(0).getCapienza())
            {
                B[0][j] = true;
                U[0][j] = true;
             }
            else
            {
                B[0][j] = false;
                U[0][j] = false;
            }
        }
        //caso generale
        for(i = 1; i < p.size(); i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < C; j++)
            {
                if(j >= p.get(i).getCapienza())
                {
                    B[i][j] = B[i-1][j] || B[i-1][j - p.get(i).getCapienza()];
                    U[i][j] = B[i-1][j-p.get(i).getCapienza()];
               }
                else
                { 
                     B[i][j] = B[i-1][j];
                     U[i][j] = false;
                }
            }
        }

        if(!B[p.size()-1][C-1])
            {
                System.out.println("-1");
            }else
            {

                i = p.size()-1;
                j = C-1;
                while( i >= 0 && j >= 0)
                {
                    if(U[i][j])
                    {
                        num_cont++;
                        System.out.println("Usato: "+p.get(i).getId()
                                +" capienza:" + p.get(i).getCapienza());
                        j = j - p.get(i).getCapienza();
                    }
                    i--;
                }
             }
           return num_cont;


    }
```

when I am running this:

```
    Contenitore c1 = new Contenitore("c1",1);
    Contenitore c2 = new Contenitore("c2",2);
    Contenitore c3 = new Contenitore("c3",3);



    lista_contenitori.add(c1);
    lista_contenitori.add(c2);
    lista_contenitori.add(c3);
    System.out.println(calcolaNumeroContenitori(4, lista_contenitori));
```

I get as result:

```
Container: c2 capacity:2
Container: c1 capacity:1
2
```

which is not the right answer. BUT if you try to think in Java everything starts from 0. I mean maybe 4 is actually read as 3 ( 0,1,2,3). What exactly am I missing here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have apparently already diagnosed the problem, but perhaps not in detail. The problem is indeed due to the highest index in an array being one less than its length.

In particular, your matrix needs to include position `C`, so it must have a dimension of `C + 1`. And for example here: `j = C-1;` and here: `B[p.size()-1][C-1]` you are going to search whether the value `C - 1` can be reached by adding up containers, which is obviously 1 less than the actual target.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the update. I tried to modify the code but I could not do it. Maybe, by summing +1 to C is not the proper way because if in reality the C=5 and inside the algorithm I set it to C=6 just to inlude the 5, C will have a size of 6 (0,1,2,3,4,5). I dunno maybe I am missing something small. I am stuck hours now with that. :(